Does shadcn/ui SelectTrigger click event blocked when another SelectContent opening?
Like the tiltle said, I have two shadcn/ui Select components, when SelectContent2 opening then i click to SelectTrigger1 the content of of SelectContent1 doesn't show immediately. Does it contain any blocking stuff like preventDefault or stopPropagation? If it does, how can i fix that?
Thanks!

this is its default behavior

do we have any way to change this? I expect it will display right after i clicked!
